# ASP.NET Core MVC modifying entity causes NullReferenceException

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, crud

I am facing a problem most of you (including me) would solve immeditately by placing a hidden input to forms, but this time I have tried almost everything. I would like to modify an InputForm entity by adding a SolarPanelType entity. Because of the loads of another options, I use viewmodels embedded as you can see

```
public class InputFormViewModel
    {
        public InputForm InputForm { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<TetoTipus> TetoTipusEnumerable { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<TetoFedes> TetoFedesEnumerable { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<TetoDoles> TetoDolesEnumerable { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<NapelemElhelyezes> NapelemElhelyezesEnumerable { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<NapelemTipus> NapelemTipusEnumerable { get; set; }
    }
```

```
public class ModifyInputFormViewModel
    {
        public InputFormViewModel InputFormViewModel;
        public SelectList SolarPanelTypesList { get; set; }
    }
```

And I initialize them in my controller like this

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Edit(int? id)
        {
            if (id == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }
            ModifyInputFormViewModel modifyInputFormViewModel = new()
            {
                InputFormViewModel = new InputFormViewModel
                {
                    InputForm = await _inputFormService.FindInputFormAsync(id),
                    TetoTipusEnumerable = await _inputFormService.GetTetoTipusokAsync(),
                    TetoFedesEnumerable = await _inputFormService.GetTetoFedesekAsync(),
                    TetoDolesEnumerable = await _inputFormService.GetTetoDolesekAsync(),
                    NapelemElhelyezesEnumerable = await _inputFormService.GetNapelemElhelyezesekAsync(),
                    NapelemTipusEnumerable = await _inputFormService.GetNapelemTipusokAsync()
                },
                SolarPanelTypesList = new SelectList(await _solarPanelTypeService.GetSolarPanelTypesAsync(), "ID", "DisplayString")
            };
            if (modifyInputFormViewModel.InputFormViewModel.InputForm == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }
            return View(modifyInputFormViewModel);
        }
```

And the POST method

```
[HttpPost, ValidateAntiForgeryToken, Authorize]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Edit(int id, ModifyInputFormViewModel modifyInputFormViewModel)
        {
            if (id != modifyInputFormViewModel.InputFormViewModel.InputForm.ID)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                await _inputFormService.ModifyInputFormAsync(modifyInputFormViewModel.InputFormViewModel.InputForm);
                return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
            }
            return View(modifyInputFormViewModel);
        }
```

Finally, here is the crucial part of Edit view

```
<form asp-action="Edit">
            <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
            <input type="hidden" asp-for="InputFormViewModel.InputForm.ID" />
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="InputFormViewModel.InputForm.SolarPanelType" class="control-label"></label>
                <select asp-for="InputFormViewModel.InputForm.SolarPanelTypeID" asp-items="@Model.SolarPanelTypesList" class="form-control"></select>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="InputFormViewModel.InputForm.MonthlyElectricityBill" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="InputFormViewModel.InputForm.MonthlyElectricityBill" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="InputFormViewModel.InputForm.MonthlyElectricityBill" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>

            <section id="TetoTipusSection">
                <h5>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.InputFormViewModel.InputForm.TetoTipus)</h5>
                <p>
                    @foreach (TetoTipus tetoTipus in Model.InputFormViewModel.TetoTipusEnumerable)
                    {
                        <label>
                            <input type="radio" asp-for="InputFormViewModel.InputForm.TetoTipusID" value="@tetoTipus.ID" /> @tetoTipus.Name
                        </label>
                        <br />
                    }
                </p>
                <hr />
            </section>

            [...]
        </form>
```

Last important information is that the view renders EXACTLY what I want, the hidden input contains InputForm.ID correctly, but then the post method receives NULL value.

Comment: `the view renders EXACTLY what I want, the hidden input contains InputForm.ID correctly, but then the post method receives NULL value` Have you checked the actual posted data in browser f12 developer tool Network tab? And please make sure the key of your posted form data can match your model properties.

Answer (score 0):

Update you code like below:-

```
<form asp-action="Edit" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

and your controller:-

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> Edit(int? ID){...}
```

Hope it will resolve your issue.

Comment: Thnaks for the effort, but HttpPost was already added, same error again.

Comment: @MészárosBarnabás Use your parameter ```ID``` instead of ```id``` in your controller. because you pass ```ID``` from view to controller action.

Answer (score 0):

fix the view, since you use AntiForgeryToken add it to form

```
<form asp-action="Edit" method="post">
 @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
```

and action input parameter should be the same as a model, remove id

```
 public async Task<IActionResult> Edit( ModifyInputFormViewModel modifyInputFormViewModel)
{
 var id= modifyInputFormViewModel.InputFormViewModel.InputForm.ID;
.......
```